# connecting problems to a DB using psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql

I am new to django.I am using eclipse IDE and my OS is windows 7.I am trying to use postgre sql.My model page is like this:[image].My settings page is like this:[image].When I try to type `python manage.py sql Mystudent` where Mystudent is my app,It shows `operational error:fe_sendauth: no password supplied`.So when I entered user name as `test` and password as `password` it shows `operational error:password authentication failed for user 'test'`.Please help me.

Comment: Please paste the text instead of screenshots of the text!

Answer (score 1):

You should specify host and port in your `settings.py` file. If you are running postgresql locally it will be:

```
'HOST': 'localhost',
'PORT': '5432',
```

**Edit**

Also note that `mydb.db` is not a valid database name for postgres.

Comment: Have you installed PostgreSQL server and psycopg2 python package? Did you create the mydb.db database?

Comment: I have installed both packages.But I have just entered mydb.db file in the settings file.I am unaware whether mydb is created or not.Is there any way to check that???

Comment: where can I type this command.?I am using eclipse and windows powershell.What should I write in the settings.py file for db name???

Comment: I am sorry for asking this, not meaning to offend. What is the reason for using postgres in the first place? For a starter sqlite3 will do the same job with no configuration pain.

Comment: This tutorial might be helpful http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/windows/getting-started-postgres-plus-tutorial-windows